# download content torrent files point to in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, bittorrent, libtorrent

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how .torrent files work, but is there a way in python to download the actual referenced **content** the .torrent file points to that would be downloaded say using a torrent client such as utorrent, but from the shell/command line using python?

The following works for simply downloading a .torrent file and sure I could open the torrent client as well do download the .torrent, but I'd rather streamline the process in the command line. Can't seem to find much online about doing this...

```
torrent = torrentutils.parse_magnet(magnet)
infohash = torrent['infoHash']
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
url = "http://torcache.net/torrent/" + infohash + ".torrent"
answer = session.get(url)
torrent_data = answer.content
buffer = BytesIO(torrent_data)
gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj = buffer)
output = open(torrent['name'], "wb")
output.write(torrent_data)
```

As far as I know i can't use libtorrent for python3 on a 64 bit windows os.

Comment: Then use 32-bit python - there is official build of libtorrent package for python3 win32. Yes, there is no maintainer for x64-package, but you can try to build it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [`magnet:` links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme) work in your web browser then a simple way to start a new torrent download from your Python script is to open the url using your web browser:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open(magnet_link)
```

Or from the command-line:

```
$ python -m webbrowser "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:ebab37b86830e1ed624c1fdbb2c59a1800135610&dn=StackOverflow201508.7z"
```

The download is performed by your actual torrent client such as uTorrent.

Answer (score 1):

BitTornado works on Windows and has a command line interface. Take a look at btdownloadheadless.py. But this written in Python 2.
http://www.bittornado.com/download.html