# How to download a file with .torrent extension from link with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, wget

I tried using wget:

```py
url = https://yts.lt/torrent/download/A4A68F25347C709B55ED2DF946507C413D636DCA
wget.download(url, 'c:/path/')
```

The result was that I got a file with the name `A4A68F25347C709B55ED2DF946507C413D636DCA` and without any extension.
Whereas when I put the link in the navigator bar and click enter, a torrent file gets downloaded.

EDIT:
Answer must be generic not case dependent.
It must be a way to download .torrent files with their original name.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `filename` inside the `content-disposition` header, i.e.:

```
import re, requests, traceback
try:
    url = "https://yts.lt/torrent/download/A4A68F25347C709B55ED2DF946507C413D636DCA"
    r = requests.get(url)
    d = r.headers['content-disposition']
    fname = re.findall('filename="(.+)"', d)
    if fname:
        with open(fname[0], 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

---

[Py3 Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/fcebd96217)

---

The code above is for `python3`. I don't have `python2` installed and I normally  don't post code without testing it.
Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11783325/797495, the method is the same.

Comment: Thank you, but please, how do you download the .torrent file with this way ?

Comment: You're welcome, you can take a look at: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-command-line-bittorrent-client.html . If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found an a way that gets the torrent files downloaded with their original name like as they were actually downloaded by putting the link in the browser's nav bar.

The solution consists of opening the user's browser from Python :

```
import webbrowser
url = "https://yts.lt/torrent/download/A4A68F25347C709B55ED2DF946507C413D636DCA"
webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)
```

Read more:
[Call to operating system to open url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216985/call-to-operating-system-to-open-url)

However the downside is :

1. I don't get the option to choose the folder where I want to save the
   file (unless I changed it in the browser but still, in case I want to save
   torrents that matches some criteria in an other
   path, it won't be possible).
2. And of course, your browser goes insane opening all those links XD

Comment: To download the actual content of the torrent using a similar method, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33912912